# homebrew uninstall/move macports UNDO

Tags: macports, homebrew

brew doctor told me to move macports: sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

So I did that and now nothing works properly. What would be the command to move macports back to where it was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

`sudo mv ~/macports /opt/local`

`mv` is a standard unix shell command to move files and directories.