# Error loading RubyGems plugin Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

any advice?

Comment: Need more info.  What OS?  What version if Rails? Of ruby? Etc....

Comment: Looks like OSX. Are you using RVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a permissions error. I appreciate everyones help and responses!

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when i first installed brew and it told me to move macports.

After i moved it back, this error went away.

This is what homebrew told me to move upon installation: [homebrew uninstall/move macports UNDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157315/homebrew-uninstall-move-macports-undo)

When installing homebrew, it tells you to move macports out of local with:

`sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports`

I started getting errors about libssl.1.0.0 not being loaded. after moving macports back, the errors went away.

`sudo mv ~/macports /opt/local`

Answer (score 2):

I just hit this after `brew doctor` told me to move macports as per @blair anderson's answer.

Rather than move MacPorts back I simply ran `rvm update` and installed the latest `ruby 2.0.0` (which I needed to do anyway) and voila… all happy.